# How to make a type of hash map with struct in rust

Tags: rust, hashmap

I am new to rust and I am looking to implement my hashmap in my struct like so

```
#[derive(Clone, Data)]
struct CheckState { 
    cool: String,
    int_cool: i32,
    hashmap_cool: HashMap<i32, String>
}
```

But i keep recieving the error code `` error[E0277]: the trait bound `HashMap<i32, std::string::String>: Data` is not satisfied `` and i do not understand why and the help is not much help

the rust help

```
 help: the following other types implement trait `Data`:
            &'static str
            ()
            (T0, T1)
            (T0, T1, T2)
            (T0, T1, T2, T3)
            (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4)
            (T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5)
            (T0,)
          and 87 others
  = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Data` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

please ignore variable names they are not the same in my code

Comment: `#[derive(Data)]` is not in the Rust's standard library. Which library are you using?

Comment: I am using the library druid but the question has been answered by jonathan ! ty

Comment: A link to the library: [Druid](https://crates.io/crates/druid).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a simple fix add:

```rust
struct CheckState { 
    cool: String,
    int_cool: i32,
    #[data(ignore)]
    hashmap_cool: HashMap<i32, String>
}
```

See the [druid documentation](https://docs.rs/druid/0.7.0/druid/derive.Data.html) for a better understanding:

> - `#[data(ignore)]` makes the generated `Data::same` function skip comparing this field.